# How do I fill a 2D array with random integers [1,9] and print out a 2D array with sums of rows at each row and sum of columns at each column?

Tags: java, arrays

The following code is what I have so far, and nothing is working at all. I am intend to Declares a 7×10 two dimensional array in the main. Pass that array to a method which fills the array with random integers [1,9]. Pass the filled array to a method which prints the two dimensional array with the sum of the row at the end of each row and the sum of the column at the end of each column. Row and column labels must also be printed. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```java
package twodimensionalarray;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Kristy7
 */
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    //This method is for generating random integers between 1 and 9.
    public static int randInt(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum;
        randNum = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
        return randNum;

    }

    //This method is for filling a 2D array with random integers 
    public static int[][] fillArray(int[][] toFill){
        int[][] toReturn = new int[0][0];

        for(int r = 0; r < toFill.length; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < toFill[0].length; c++){
                toReturn[toFill[r]][toFill[c]] = randInt(toFill);
            }

        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    //This method is for for summing rows and columns, and printing rows, columns, the sum of ruws at each row, and the sum of columns at each column.
    public static void summingRC(int[][] toSum){
        int[] colSums = new int[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < toSum.length; i++){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        int sum = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < toSum.length; r++) {

        for (int c = 0; c < toSum[r].length; c++) {
            sum += toSum[c][r];
            colSums[c] += toSum[r][c];
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    System.out.println(colSums);


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declare a 7x10 2D array 
        int [][] twoDArray = new int[7][10];

        //call fillArray method.
        int[][] fillingArray = fillArray(twoDArray);

        //call SummingRC method
        summingRC(fillingArray);

    }

}
```

Comment: When submitting code, please paste it, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor. This will format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your code is that you initialized the two dim array in the line `int[][] toReturn = new int[0][0];`.  Here you give the array size and dimension, then in the loop you are trying to populate the array based on the `toFill` length. Because arrays are fixed in size and do not expand dynamically you can not do this.

Below is the same style code which gots an arrayindexoutofboundsexception. What I suggest to you is that you give the length and dimensions to the method and then initialize the array with these sizes.

The code below is also getting an exception because of the same problem you did which is initializing the array to a size then trying to add elements to it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] []  x =new int[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            x[i][j]=i+j;

        }

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.println(x[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of issues with this code as you are probably aware. Most of them stem from incorrectly instantiating and accessing arrays. I fixed it up:

```
public static int randInt(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum;
    randNum = rand.nextInt(9)+1;
    return randNum;

}

//This method is for filling a 2D array with random integers 
public static int[][] fillArray(int[][] toFill){
    int[][] toReturn = new int[toFill.length][toFill[0].length];

    for(int r = 0; r < toFill.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < toFill[0].length; c++){
            toReturn[r][c] = randInt();
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}

//This method is for for summing rows and columns, and printing rows, columns, the sum of ruws at each row, and the sum of columns at each column.
public static void summingRC(int[][] toSum){
    int[] colSum = new int[toSum[0].length];
    int[] rowSum = new int[toSum.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < toSum.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < toSum[i].length; j++){
            colSum[j] += toSum[i][j];
            rowSum[i] += toSum[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Matrix: ");
    print2dArray(toSum);
    System.out.println("Col sum:");
    printArray(colSum);
    System.out.println("Row sum:");
    printArray(rowSum);

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * 
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declare a 7x10 2D array 
    int [][] twoDArray = new int[7][10];

    //call fillArray method.
    int[][] fillingArray = fillArray(twoDArray);

    //call SummingRC method
    summingRC(fillingArray);

}

public static void print2dArray(int[][] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] +  " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printArray(int arr[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] +  " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

There's a lot of places where you are instantiating an array with 0 length. Which is basically just a useless array at that point because you can't put any values into it. Ex:

```
int[] colSums = new int[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8. You can do this elegantly by `Stream`.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Q47129466 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] mat = get(5, 5);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mat));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rowSum(mat)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columnSum(mat)));
  }

  public static int[][] get(int width, int height) {
    return IntStream.range(0, height)
        .mapToObj(c -> IntStream.range(0, width)
            .map(r -> (int) (9 * Math.random() + 1))
            .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
  }

  public static int[] rowSum(int[][] matrix) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix).mapToInt(row -> IntStream.of(row).sum()).toArray();
  }

  public static int[] columnSum(int[][] matrix) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix).reduce((a, b) -> add(a, b)).orElse(new int[0]);
  }

  public static int[] add(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] sum = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
      sum[i] = (i < a.length ? a[i] : 0) + (i < b.length ? b[i] : 0);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```